# Parse htm page/table to json, nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, html-parsing

I am searching the solution for parsing below html table to json:

```
 <div id="content">
    <h1>content-information</h1>
              <table class="testinformation">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>hello</th>
                <th>test_text</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="https://example.com">hello1</a></td>
                <td><a href="https://example.com/test_text">test_text</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="https://example.com">hello2</a></td>
                <td><a href="https://example.com/test_text2">test_text2</a></td>
            </tr>            
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Tried cheerio, cherrio-tableparser, but without success...

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [node-html-to-json](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/node-html-to-json)

It's easy to use and well documented.

Comment: Thank You. Still I can't parse table, it is not easy to start working with that package, but I will try.